# Internationalization of QML application using i18n

Tags: application-development, qml, internationalization

Does someone know all the steps needed to have the apps translated in multiple languages?

I am using in my QML files `i18n.tr()`  , and such words I need to translate

I performed below steps ( `~/QtCreator/OwnDictionary` is project directory ), but the apps is always in English :

```
roman@roman-ubuntu:~/QtCreator/OwnDictionary$ mkdir locale
roman@roman-ubuntu:~/QtCreator/OwnDictionary$ xgettext -C --qt --keyword=tr --add-comments=TRANSLATORS OwnDictionary.qml -p locale -o messages.pot
roman@roman-ubuntu:~/QtCreator/OwnDictionary$ ls locale
messages.pot
roman@roman-ubuntu:~/QtCreator/OwnDictionary$ cd locale/
roman@roman-ubuntu:~/QtCreator/OwnDictionary/locale$ msginit -i messages.pot -o sk.po
-- I edited here the sk.po to add Slovak translation
roman@roman-ubuntu:~/QtCreator/OwnDictionary/locale$ msgmerge -U sk.po messages.pot
roman@roman-ubuntu:~/QtCreator/OwnDictionary/locale$ mkdir -p sk/LC_MESSAGES
-- in manifest.json I found such line :     "name": 
"com.ubuntu.developer.username.owndictionary", so I executed this :
roman@roman-ubuntu:~/QtCreator/OwnDictionary/locale$ msgfmt sk.po -o sk/LC_MESSAGES/com.ubuntu.developer.username.owndictionary.mo
```

Maybe some special environment settings are needed as well?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your app needs to set a couple of env. variables to tell gettext which .mo file to use and where to find it.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Triggering.html

Comment: I am not much clever now . I tested many enviroments e.g. export LC_ALL="sk_SK.utf8"  and then I started the application using qmlscene command , but the application was always in english ...

Comment: @user262898: What about bindtextdomain and textdomain?

Comment: I added this to the code , but it did not help :                 i18n.bindtextdomain("com.ubuntu.developer.username.owndictionary", "locale")        
    i18n.domain = "com.ubuntu.developer.username.owndictionary"

Comment: @user262898: Well, I know nothing about QML.. But as the second argument passed to i18n.bindtextdomain I would try the full path to locale, not just "locale". I suppose you also need some equivalent to 'setlocale (LC_ALL, "");' in C programs. It tells the program to apply the locale from the locale environment.